# I'm filtering an array elements based on an array of strings, however, I'm turning the string array into an array of objects. Do I need another loop?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of elements where each element is a card from a certain game and I am being successful in filtering the cards based on another array like this:

```
let regions = ['Noxus', 'Demacia', 'Shadow Isles', 'Freljord', 'Ionia', 'Piltover & Zaun']

filteredByRegion(cards){
    return cards.filter((card) => {
        return this.regions.includes(card.region)
    })
}
```

However, now I'm trying to turn the array of strings into an array of objects where the strings are gonna be just one of the object's properties.

```
let regions = [
    { name: "Noxus", active: true },
    { name: "Demacia", active: true },
    { name: "Shadow Isles", active: false },
    { name: "Freljord", active: true },
    { name: "Ionia", active: true },
    { name: "Piltover & Zaun", active: false },
]
```

Now I only want to get the cards from regions that have the `active` property set to `true`. This means I need to get all active regions before doing the cards filter. So I've changed the function to this:

```
filteredByRegion(cards){
    let activeRegions = regions.filter((region) => {
        return region.active === true
    })

    return cards.filter((card) => {
        return this.regions.includes(card.region)
    })
}
```

Now I'm just a bit confused how to change the `cards.filter()` so that it only returns the cards whose region property matches one of the active regions in my `activeRegions` variable. Do I need a for loop inside the cards filter which loops over each active region and place the return `this.regions.includes(card.region)` in that loop?

Comment: No no, the region strings array was how my array used to be, and the region objects array is how it is right now. So I want the result from the cards filtering to include all cards whose region property matches one of the regions in the regions array based on the name property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a Set (or array) of active regions by filtering and mapping the `regions` array of objects. Then you can create another Set of the `this.regions` which are contained in those active regions. Finally, filter the `cards` parameter by whether it's included in that Set:

```
filteredByRegion(cards){
  const activeRegionsSet = new Set(
    regions
      .filter(({ active }) => active)
      .map(({ name }) => name)
  );
  const theseActiveRegions = new Set(this.regions.filter(region => activeRegionsSet.has(region)));
  return cards.filter(card => theseActiveRegions.has(card.region));
}
```

Or, if you don't like destructuring:

```
filteredByRegion(cards){
  const activeRegionsSet = new Set(
    regions
      .filter(obj => obj.active)
      .map(obj => obj.name)
  );
  const theseActiveRegions = new Set(this.regions.filter(region => activeRegionsSet.has(region)));
  return cards.filter(card => theseActiveRegions.has(card.region));
}
```

The Sets are there for decreased computational complexity (`Set#has` is `O(1)`, whereas `Array#includes` is `O(n)`). But if you're more comfortable with arrays, the same code would look like:

```
filteredByRegion(cards){
  const activeRegions = regions
    .filter(({ active }) => active)
    .map(({ name }) => name);
  const theseActiveRegions = this.regions.filter(region => activeRegions.includes(region));
  return cards.filter(card => theseActiveRegions.includes(card.region));
}
```

It doesn't matter much, but you could iterate over the original `regions` array only once instead of twice by pushing inside a conditional test, though it's less functional:

```
const activeRegions = [];
for (const { active, name } of regions) {
  if (active) {
    activeRegions.push(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: May I ask some questions since I'm confused by the code a little bit. First of all, does my code which gets the active regions not work fine? const activeRegions = regions.filter(({ active }) => active).map(({ name }) => name); I'm not sure what's the functionality of the curly braces around active and name. Same goes for the .map() in this case.

Comment: Your original code's `activeRegions` is an array of objects, but you only want the strings inside the objects which are `active` - you need to go farther in order to be able to efficiently check the `cards` array against it later. I prefer the destructuring syntax because it uses only the minimally required property for what's needed, but you don't have to use it.